# Why this generator implementation does not work in Racket?

Tags: racket, continuations

I'm trying to implement generators in racket using `call/cc`, I have this code so far

```lisp
(define (foo2)
  (define (g abort)
    (define-syntax-rule
      (yield x)
      (call/cc (lambda (k)
                 (set! g k)
                 (abort x))))
    (yield 'foo)
    (yield 'bar)
    (yield 'tar)
    (abort 'end))
  (thunk (call/cc g)))
```

If I play with this in the REPL it seems to be working correctly

```
foo.rkt> (define g (foo2))
foo.rkt> (g)
'foo
foo.rkt> (g)
'bar
foo.rkt> (g)
'tar
foo.rkt> (g)
'end
foo.rkt> (g)
'end
foo.rkt>
```

But if I try to call g inside a list, it hangs and I have no idea what is happening

```
foo.rkt> (define g (foo2))
foo.rkt> (list (g) (g) (g))
;; prompt is not released
```

What is going on? Where my generator implementation is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `(list (g) (g) (g))`? Well it is basically this in CPS:

```
(g& (lambda (g1) ; continuation g1 
     (g& (lambda (g2)
          (g& (lambda (g3)
               (list& g1 g2 g3 halt))))
```

You are replacing `g&`, but all of you `yield` share the same initial `abort` which is continuation `g1` and you will never ever reach continuation `g2` since every time `abort` is called you run continuation `g1`. If you step through you'll notice that this continuation gets fed all the yield values but eventually it calls `abort`. Even if you remove the last call it will always call the second `(g)` in your expression.

It helps to know `call/cc&` is this:

```
(define (call/cc& f cc)
  (f (lambda (v ignored-cc) 
       (cc v)) 
     cc))
```

Now `g` in CPS would look something like this. Notice the `abort` are free variables in there and they will be the same even if you replace `g&`

```
(define (g& abort cont)
  (call/cc& (lambda (k cc)
              (set!& g& 
                     k 
                     (lambda (undefined) 
                       (abort 'foo cc))))
            (lambda (ignored1)
              (call/cc& (lambda (k cc)
                          (set!& g& 
                                 k 
                                 (lambda (undefined) 
                                   (abort 'bar cc))))
                        (lambda (ignored2)
                          (call/cc& (lambda (k cc)
                                      (set!& g& 
                                             k 
                                             (lambda (undefined) 
                                               (abort 'tar cc))))
                                    (lambda (ignored3)
                                      (abort 'end cont)))))))))
```

As a fix I guess you need to control what you set as `g`. Eg. instead of
`(set! g k)` something like this perhaps:

```
(set! g (lambda (new-abort)
          (set! abort new-abort)
          (k 'ignored)))
```

Then the list expression works as expected. Why it worked in the REPL is due to [continuation prompts](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html#%28part._prompt-model%29).

Comment: thanks Slywester, a quick question how to do you step through this? there is an debugging tool for such kind of problems?

Comment: I tried your suggestion like this https://gist.github.com/dhilst/47c4cac6fa2a4f43b4a08741bc4f053b but it didn't work for me if I call `foo3` then `(g)` returns `end`. If I do `(call/cc (lambda (k) ... (k 'ignored)` the call returns immediately, I want it to halt until g is called again. Continuations are really hard to reason about

Comment: Okay I could get to a working generator `foo5` here https://gist.github.com/dhilst/a03d07ccf89a70299d6c84a27088a05f

Comment: @geckos I wish there was a transform to cps somewhere, bit I do it by hand and it takes forever. Stepping through your original code is easily done in DrRacket and you see the infinite loop there, but scheme does cps under the hood to implement `call/cc`. A few modern implementation doesn't do it always, but have to when someone used `call/cc`.

Comment: I guess writing code in CPS would help me to build an intuition about call/cc, I will try it, thanks for your help :)